# Python - Adding one to variable after each call

Tags: python

```
count = 0

def lol(count):
    x = count + 1
    print(x)
```

Currently i am calling this function within another file in my python program, and count is = 1 everytime it is ran, im unsure why, im trying to make it +1 after every time it is ran.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: It will always just print count+1 because that what the code does. In fact the above code won't do anything because you never call lol()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never modifying `count`, and only printing the result of `x = 0 + 1`

This would do what you want, however, you should re-consider your need for global variables

```
count = 0

def lol():
    global count
    count += 1
    print(count)
```